# Why is my ArrayList duplicating my items when added to another ArrayList in Android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a checkable RelativeLayout that I've obtained from [this](http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html) tutorial. Everything is exactly the same except that I am adding the data from one ArrayList to another when the user moves on to the next step of the "Wizard" which I am using [this](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid) library for.

For some reason, when the user gets to the last step in the wizard, the selected items are duplicated more than once. For example, if the user selects:

> choice 1, choice5, choice 7

The last step in the "wizard" displays this:

> Choice 1
>       choice 1
>       choice 5
>       choice 7
>       choice 1
>       choice 5
>       choice 7
>       choice 1
>       choice 5
>       choice 7

This is the code to add the selected items from the "selection" ArrayList to the final result ArrayList. (I have two arrays because the other gathers items from another selection screen of a different type of ArrayList):

```
    final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
                    // Item position in adapter
                    int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                    // Add team if item is checked == TRUE!
                    if(checkedItems.valueAt(i))
                        selectedTeams.add(myAdapter.getItem(position));
                    for (int j = 0; j < selectedTeams.size(); j++) {
                        selectedTeams.get(i);
                        System.out.print("option list size");
                        System.out.print(selectedTeams.size());
                        CreateProduct.nsList.add(selectedTeams.get(j).getBaseName());

                    }
                }
                if(selectedTeams.size() < 2)
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Need to select two or more items.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                {
                    // Just logging the output.
                    for(NSBaseModel t : selectedTeams)
                        Log.d("SELECTED TEAMS: ", t.getBaseName());

                }
```

The logcat from one step to the next shows only single entries for each selected items, not multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is "on check" of an item. You could move to later to ensure only happens once, i.e. on wizard "next".

Or you could clear the items before the for loop. Without that, nothing would ever get removed from the list and each tick adds every item multiple times.

```
selectedTeams.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
    // Item position in adapter
    int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
    // Add team if item is checked == TRUE!
    if(checkedItems.valueAt(i))
        selectedTeams.add(myAdapter.getItem(position));
```

Comment: The code I posted is in the wizards on next for that step. do you think that if I clear the selectedTeams they wouldn't be added to the CreateProduct.nsList? Do you think it possible that the int j in the second for loop could be causing issues? Specifically j++?

Comment: I don't know, have you tried debugging this? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Ok. I added this line after CreateProduct.nsList in the for loop: `Log.i(AppConfig.TAG_DEF, selectedTeams.get(j).getBaseName());` And in the logcat it shows duplicate items being added to nsList. Within that for loop, do you think selectedTeams.get(i) could be causing the error if I'm calling ..nsList.add(selectedTeams.get(j)... using the "j" intent?

Comment: Nope not that one. I changed that and still getting the duplicate entries.

Comment: I debugged my app with breakpoints and I'm still confused. If I check two items, it shows two items checked in the debug console all the way to the ..nsList.add(selectedTeams.get(j).getBaseName());

Comment: thank you for giving me the link for debugging. I guess I wasn't debugging properly. After adding break points and separate log tags for each break point, I found that having the for loop to add items to nsList within the first for loop caused the duplication. I put the second for loop outside of  the first for loop and the result is as it should be. Thank you again very much! Please add that to your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: "separate log tags for each break point" When you use breakpoints, you can hover over variables to see what's in them, so logging becomes less nessasary.

Comment: Re updating my answer, it's OK, you can write your own answer, as I don't understand how you fixed it.